# Reflect thinks struct Value is also a ptr?

Tags: reflection, go

I have a data structure like this demo. As you can see, `foo` has an embedded pointer to `bar`:

```
type foo struct {
    *bar
}

type bar struct {
    S []byte
}
```

And I'm using the `reflect` package like this:

```
func test(x interface{}) {

    var v = reflect.ValueOf(x)

    if v.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        fmt.Println("was a struct")

    // panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Elem on struct Value
    //  v = v.Elem()

    // panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Field on ptr Value
        v = v.FieldByName("S")
    }
}

func main() {
    var f foo
    test(f)
    fmt.Println(string(f.S))
}
```

So `v.Kind()` is recognized as a `reflect.Struct`, but if I try to treat it like a struct by using `.FieldByName("S")`, it panics because it thinks `v` is a `ptr`.

So then if I try to treat it like a `ptr` by calling `.Elem()`, it panics because it thinks `v` is a `struct`.

I've tried `reflect.Indirect()`, as well as a few other things, but I can't figure out how to get the field of an embedded pointer.

Is there a way to get the `reflect.Value` representation from an embedded pointer to a struct?

***Demo:*** http://play.golang.org/p/n0eea6XW3I

---

***EDIT:*** Also tried `v = v.FieldByName("bar")`, but got:

> `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

Comment: I have to look at the documentation to be sure, but my immediate intuition is that maybe embedded types confuse it.

Comment: It's definitely the embedded type confusing it. Try changing bar to not be a pointer and it doesn't crash. Alteratively: remove references to f.S and give the *bar a name and it works. I'm looking through the documentation to see if this behavior is mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @Jsor: Thanks, yeah I can see how there would be some confusion there. I couldn't find anything in `reflect` that deals specifically with embedded pointers.

Comment: I got it, I'll give an answer in a second. It's actually really tricky and subtle, but there's a bug in your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing we need to realize is that the line `var f foo` is equivalent to `f := foo{}`. This initializes the internal field `bar` (of type *bar) to its zero value... nil. The behavior of embedded types and reflect seems to be that it treats the embedded type's fields as fields of the type itself. So when you request `v.FieldByName("S")` it's trying to find that field in f's member, bar, which is nil.

You're trying to do this `(*f.bar).S`. (In Go the explicit pointer dereference isn't needed, but it makes my point). Now the question is: if you change is to `v.FieldByName("bar")` why does it give an error? Same reason.

Look closely at the stack trace, the `FieldByName` line no longer crashes, the line that crashes is `fmt.Println(string(f.S))`. Again, semantically you're doing `(*f.bar).S`. But the member "bar" is nil, so you are, in fact, doing a nil pointer dereference.

You can fix both errors by changing `var f foo` to `f := foo{&bar{}}`.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. That makes sense. Just the panic messages are confusing. Totally makes sense though. Much appreciated!

Comment: @cookiemonster The error message is definitely confusing. It should really say "attempt to dereference nil pointer" rather than giving you the weird "reflect.Field on pointer" error.

Answer (score 1):

i was getting this error "  panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Elem on struct Value" bcz of this line "reflect.ValueOf(parameterName).Elem()"

1.When i am using Elem() in reflex ,it means parameterName inside valueOf()  should be a pointer to structure

```
func Search(flight interface{}, key string) string {

  val := reflect.ValueOf(flight).Elem()

  for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
    valueField := val.Field(i)
    typeField := val.Type().Field(i)
    if key == strings.ToLower(typeField.Name) {
      return valueField.Interface().(string)
    }
  }
  return ""
}
```

Now while calling search function my call should be like this!
result := Search(&flights, key)