# reflect: call of reflect.Value.FieldByName on ptr Value

Tags: go

I have a data structure like this demo.

```
type Family struct {
   first string
   last string
}
type Person struct {
   name string
   family *Family
}

func main(){
   per1 := Person{name:"niki",family:&Familys{first:"yam",last:"bari"}}
   Check(per1)
}
```

and the code:

```
var validate *validator.Validate
func Check(data interface{}) {
    var v = reflect.ValueOf(data)

    if v.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        fmt.Println("was a struct")
        v = v.FieldByName("family").FieldByName("last")
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

when i do not use point for Family , it back "bari" and it is ok.But with point , there is this error .

> reflect: call of reflect.Value.FieldByName on ptr Value

I searched a lot but i can not find answer can help.

Comment: I searched and and found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085485/reflect-thinks-struct-value-is-also-a-ptr and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537525/reflect-value-fieldbyname-causing-panic - it looks the same doesn't it? 
Do those help you solve your problem

Comment: I check them but when i use Elem() , there is another error and  my per1 structure is correct .@kabanus

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As you've noted, `family` is `*Family`. And as the error says, you cannot call `.FieldByName(...)` on a `reflect.Value` where that value is a pointer.

Instead you need to indirect the pointer, to get the value that it points to, and call `.FieldByName(...)` on that.

```
familyPtr := v.FieldByName("family")
v = reflect.Indirect(familyPtr).FieldByName("last")
```

See docs on indirect: https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Indirect

Comment: Yes,I must use Indirect().Thanks @Zak